# Who are the actresses in Mariah Carey's Through the Rain?

Tags: pop, music-video, hip-hop, soul

From [Mariah Carey - Through The Rain (Official Music Video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRNdmkH8zrI)

1st

> [image]

2nd

> [image]

Comment: According to the [Cast list](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7349742/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_cl_sm), there are only 3 actors in that clip: Mariah Carey (as herself), her mother (Jamie-Lynn Sigler) and her father (J.D. Williams). Can we be absolutely certain it isn't Mariah in disguise?

Comment: @Mast edited post. not sure w/c 1 is Jamie-Lynn Sigler lol. i'm seriously so bad with faces.

Comment: @BCLC updated my answer to reflect your edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actress in your first screenshot is [Jamie-Lynn Sigler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie-Lynn_Sigler). The second is uncredited.

---

According to [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7349742/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_cl_sm) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Through_the_Rain#Music_video) sources on the music video, the cast is limited to:

- [Mariah Carey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariah_Carey) (herself)
- [Jamie-Lynn Sigler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie-Lynn_Sigler) (Mariah's mother)
- [J.D. Williams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._D._Williams) (Mariah's father)

This is supported by the opening statement regarding the music video in the Wikipedia article:

> *The music video, directed by Dave Meyers, was filmed on location in New York City on September 30, and October 1, 2002. It is loosely based on the singer's parents, Alfred and Patricia Carey, during the times that she was conceived. **The characters are played by J. D. Williams and Jamie-Lynn Sigler respectively** and incorporates themes from Charmbracelet as well as from Carey's life.*

Furthermore, the synopsis describes the introduction to the music video as:

> *The video begins with a view of a Carey's personal family album. As the pages open, the camera zooms to one particular photograph, **of her young mother facing a wall, with her back turned**. As the picture comes into full view, it turns into actual footage. Her mother turns around in anguish, as her own mother begins shouting at her and calling her a disgrace to the family.*

From this, we can conclude that the actress in your screenshot is Jamie-Lynn Sigler portraying Mariah's young mother.

---

<sub>*Emphasis mine.*</sub>

Comment: thanks. edited post. not sure w/c 1 is Jamie-Lynn Sigler lol. i'm seriously so bad with faces.

Comment: @BCLC the younger girl (the one in your 1st screenshot) is Jamie-Lynn Sigler.

Comment: oh wow. it's just like mandy patinkin. looks so different in princess bride compared to homeland. thanks!